# The requested URL not found in this server in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

Whenever I click a link it says:

> Not Found
>   The requested url /project/contact/ was not found in this server
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I found out that *index.php* is not showing in the url, and my *.htaccess file* is also looks fine.

Can anyone help me find the solution?

Comment: i edited the apache2.conf and changed allow overrides none to all and its worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto settings > permalinks > Common settings > Activate the Post name
then Do the correction in .htaccess
Again 
Goto settings > permalinks > Common settings > Activate the Plain
then it will run good.